# PHP Database only inputs the last value

Tags: php, ios, database, xcode

I have almost no experience with PHP and right now I'm stuck at the total beginning, which is really frustrating. I have a code, which seems to work. From my app I can input values and put them in my PHP database. Thing is that he only inputs the very last value from my PHP code. So the app aside: If I only use the PHP code to input something in my database he always only takes the last value. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "xxx";
$DB_User = "xxx";
$DB_Pass = "xxx";
$DB_Table = "contacts";

if (isset ($_GET["name"]))
    $name = $_GET["name"];
else
    $name = "Blade";

if (isset ($_GET["lastname"]))
    $lastname = $_GET["lastname"];
else
    $lastname = "Xcoder";

if (isset ($_GET["number"]))
    $number = $_GET["number"];
else
    $number = "111";

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (Firtname) values('$name');";
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (Lastname) values('$lastname');";
 $sql = "insert into $DB_Table (Number) values('$number');";

$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "faild";
}// end else
?>
```

To clarify: If I only have the firstname value, he inputs it in the right place (firstname). If I have a firstname and lastname value, he only inputs the lastname value, but not the firstname value (still at the right place lastname). And the same for number. If I have a firstname, lastname and a number, he only puts the number in the right place but not the other values. In addition I can only do it once. If I want to enter another contact he always says (Duplicate entry 'myentry' for key 'PRIMARY').

Comment: You have an SQLi vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite your query, 2 ways to solve. Either 3 different variables, or 1 variable with 3 queries in it. I would prefer the 2nd option

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (Firtname) values('$name');";
$sql .= "insert into $DB_Table (Lastname) values('$lastname');";
$sql .= "insert into $DB_Table (Number) values('$number');";

$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Or if it can be 1 row in the table, as it is the same table anyways:

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (Firtname,Lastname,Number) values('$name','$lastname','$number');";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are overwriting $sql on the next 2 lines, so the final sql line is what is inserted.

Your sql is wrong if you want them all in the same row.

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (Firtname,lastname,number) values('$name','$lastname','$number');";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `$sql` string each time.

Perhaps you meant to use the `.=` to append all three queries together.  What is the structure for database tables?

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (Firtname) values('$name');";
$sql .= "insert into $DB_Table (Lastname) values('$lastname');";
$sql .= "insert into $DB_Table (Number) values('$number');";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting your `$sql` statements. You have to execute them. By doing:

```
$sql = "Insert INTO..."
```

you merely set a a variable. You need to ru each query using `mysql_query()`.

I'm also guessing that you want to do this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_TABLE (Firstname, Lastname, Number) VALUES ('$name', '$lastname', '$number')
```

Finally, it is **crucial** that you sanitise your inputs:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name"]);
```

Thanks to this you avoid an SQL Injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you use the same variable name (`$sql`) for all 3 queries. Use `$sql1`, `$sql2` and `$sql3` instead. Also, call `mysql_query` for each one (but only if you've set it).

Like this:

```
$sql1 = "insert into $DB_Table (Firtname) values('$name');";
$sql2 = "insert into $DB_Table (Lastname) values('$lastname');";
$sql3 = "insert into $DB_Table (Number) values('$number');";

if (isset ($sql1))
{
    $res1 = mysql_query($sql1,$con) or die(mysql_error());
}

if (isset ($sql2))
{
    $res2 = mysql_query($sql2,$con) or die(mysql_error());
}

if (isset ($sql3))
{
    $res3 = mysql_query($sql3,$con) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: bad advice since the table is all the same, his sql is bad all together.

Comment: Ok, true, everything can be done in a single query. But at least it fixes his problem...